# how implement radio button behavior?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I have two UIButtons. they behave like check boxes(both buttons can select at a time). But I want **only one button can select at a time** (like radio buttons). How can I do it? 
This how I implement checkbox button feature.

```
if ([btnAnswer1 isSelected]) {
        [btnAnswer1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnAnswer1 setSelected:NO];

    }else {
        [btnAnswer1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [btnAnswer1 setSelected:YES];
    }



    if ([btnAnswer2 isSelected]) {
        [btnAnswer2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnAnswer2 setSelected:NO];
    }else {
        [btnAnswer2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [btnAnswer2 setSelected:YES];
    }
```

Comment: Maybe, it will be better to use `UISegmentedControl`?

Comment: read this blog .... http://www.developers-life.com/radio-buttons-in-iphone-application.html it may help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I haven't check, just try with given modified code.

```
    if ([btnAnswer1 isSelected]) 
    {
        [btnAnswer1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnAnswer1 setSelected:NO];
        selected = FALSE;
        [btnAnswer2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState :UIControlStateSelected];
        [btnAnswer2 setSelected:YES];
    }
    else 
    {
        [btnAnswer1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState: UIControlStateSelected];
        [btnAnswer1 setSelected:YES];
        [btnAnswer2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_unchecked.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnAnswer2 setSelected:NO];
        selected = TRUE;
    }

    if ([btnAnswer2 isSelected]) 
    {
        [btnAnswer2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_unchecked.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnAnswer2 setSelected:NO];
        [btnAnswer1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState: UIControlStateSelected];
        [btnAnswer1 setSelected:YES];
    }
    else 
    {
        [btnAnswer2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState: UIControlStateSelected];
        [btnAnswer2 setSelected:YES];
        [btnAnswer1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_unchecked.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnAnswer1 setSelected:NO];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I usually implement radio buttons is:

```
-(void) radioButtonWasSelected:(RadioButton*) which
{
    //set all radio buttons to unselected
    //set 'which' to selected

    //do something with 'which'

}
```